# How to increment and decrement value of label in tableview and make total price from label value in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image: My tableview look like this.]

now cell value are dynamically and its look after calling api. 
  [image: my tableview look like this after dynamically add value.]

I want to make total of all tickets price at last. I refer this link [How do I increment/decrement a label value with two buttons pressed in tableview Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299611/how-do-i-increment-decrement-a-label-value-with-two-buttons-pressed-in-tableview) and make changes in my code but didn't work for me.

```
 struct Product {
     var price = 0
  }

class TicketBookingVC: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var mainTblView: UIView!

var bookingDetails = NSDictionary()
var productArray = [Product]()
var product : Product!
private var counterValue = 1
var productIndex = 0
var counterLbl = UILabel()

@IBOutlet weak var bookBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var eventImg: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tblView.delegate = self
    tblView.dataSource = self

        for _ in 0...10{
            productArray.append(Product(price: 1))
        }
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    else if section == 1{
        return 4
    }
    else{
        return 1
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellfirst", for: indexPath)

        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
  else if indexPath.section == 1 {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellsecond", for: indexPath)

        let mainViewCell = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2000) as! UIView
        let normalView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2001) as! UIView
        let eventName = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2003) as! UILabel
        let eventPrice = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2004) as! UILabel
        counterLbl = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2007) as! UILabel
        let decrementBtn = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2005) as! UIButton
        let incrementBtn = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2006) as! UIButton

        decrementBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.decrementbuttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        incrementBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.incrementbuttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

        product = productArray[indexPath.row]
        counterLbl.text = "\(product.price)"

       cell.selectionStyle = .none
       return cell
  }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellthird", for: indexPath)

        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.section == 0{

        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    else{
        return 80
        //return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}

@objc func decrementbuttonClicked() {
    print("Button decrement")
    if(counterValue != 1){
        counterValue -= 1;
    }
    self.counterLbl.text = "\(counterValue)"
    product.price = counterValue
}

@objc func incrementbuttonClicked() {
    counterValue += 1;
    self.counterLbl.text = "\(counterValue)"
    product.price = counterValue
}

func addProductToCart(product: Product, atindex: Int) {
    productArray[atindex] = product
    calculateTotal()
}

func calculateTotal()
{
    var totalValue = 0
    for objProduct in productArray {

        totalValue += objProduct.price
    }
    self.eventPrice.text = "Total \(totalValue)"
  }
 }
```

when I increment or decrement value of first cell it reflect in 4th cell. please help. I am new at swift.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to cell reuse. You should set a model for each cell

Comment: don't understand. Here no of row is depend on array value which is dynamically.

Comment: Or you can write the click event of the button inside the cell. When you click the add button or the decrease button, the value of counterLbl is changed inside the cell, and the click event of the button is called back to the outside through the block.